# How do I chart timeseries data organized by one of the columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-charts

Here's what seems to be a simple common thing in excel/sheets that I can't seem to be able to google in the right way. three columns: timestamp, email, things_done.

I want a chart with time as the X axis, things_done as the Y axis, and a line for each email.

The things_done could be grouped by week or even month and that would be pretty good.

Ideally I would be able to point some tool at this data and be able to do various things with it like choose weather to group by week or month, look at 5-week moving average, etc.

I've been able to sort of achieve this with multiple sheets to get to a pivot table, but the resultant "smooth" chart doesn't want to consistently connect the dots. And in general my setup is very inflexible.

Is there a way (or third-party tool) to go straight from my source data described above to a nice looking chart with the time aggregation of my choosing (and bonus points for ability to add moving average)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the data before charting it. The pivot formula in the example below is:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A, sum(C) where C is not null group by A pivot B")
```

You can add another field to use as a filter.  For example, if D2 were an email selection, you could use:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A, sum(C) where C is not null"&IF(D2<>""," and B='"&D2&"'","")&" group by A pivot B")
```

[image: Pivot Example]

Comment: Thanks! I get "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings.". FYI my columns B and A and different from your example. So I'm using `=QUERY('my-other-sheet'!A:C,"select B, sum(C) where C is not null"&IF(D2<>""," and A='"&D2&"'","")&" group by B pivot A")`